# Getting fine uploader's new file name

Tags: fine-uploader

I am having difficulties finding information on how to get the uuid name that fine uploader assigns when it uploads.  I want to add some code if the response is success then it will return the file name that fine uploader just uploaded into my aws folder.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// ...
onComplete: function (id, name, responseJson, xhr) {
    var uuid = this.getUuid(id);
    // ...
}
// ...
```

[`onComplete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete) : Is called when the item has finished uploading *successfully* (i.e., `{ success: true }` ). You may want to get the uuid on other events. Just remember that as long as you have the file or blob's `id` you can use `getUuid`.

[`getUuid`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUuid) : Will return the UUID of the item with the associated id.